# How can I detect the size of a WebView in the HTML using either CSS or Javascript?

Tags: html, xaml, css, windows-8, winrt-xaml

We are building a Windows 8 app and we'd like to support the snapped view. Some of our content is loaded from 3rd party HTML pages where we embed a WebView in the XAML. Everything loads fine, but we'd like to take advantage of HTML5/CSS3 to detect dimensions and choose the appropriate CSS to render the page.

So our WebView looks something like this:

```
<WebView x:Name="_WebView" 
         Source="{Binding NavigationUri, Mode=OneWay}"
         Width="275"
         Height="200" />
```

This is just an example, but how can the HTML page know that the size of the window is 275px by 200px?

Answer (score 1):

[Edited for better approach]

You could inject some Javascript from the C# side. See [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/37f760ff-c476-4602-b1c0-b7a62c484d6a) for an example. Since you know the width of the control in your C# code, you can then easily set some variable or invoke a function.

Comment: I've tried those, but I either get `undefined`, `0`, or `1366` (which is the size of the surface screen)

Comment: +1 That does answer my question, but unfortunately we can't do that. The HTML we render comes from different 3rd parties and we want to give them a way to detect the size using HTML/CSS/JS. I wish there was a way to run Firebug inside the windows 8 app WebView :P

Comment: Couldn't you inject a new function `getScreenHeight()` which returns a fixed value (determined in C#) and have the 3rd-party-code call it?

Comment: Because the 3rd party HTML folks are untrustworthy and we would like to give them something simple to use. The HTML is reused for all clients. Having a custom method would also require custom code to detect if the HTML is running in WinRT.